# How to create shortcut that opens Outlook PAB file (Personal Address Book)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2003, address-book

I would like to place a shortcut on my desktop that points to my .PAB file and opens it. There is no file association for .PAB files.

I tried to open with outlook.exe but that gives me an error about incorrect command line parameters.

I tried the Windows address book program (`c:\program files\outlook express\wab.exe`) but that fails likewise.

This article [Create a Desktop shortcut to an Outlook folder](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/660) offers suggestions for command line parameters but I could not find the right one.

Current versions: Outlook 2003 and Windows XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way experimenting with the options mentioned in the linked article.

Create a desktop shortcut as:

`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\OUTLOOK.EXE"  /select outlook:contacts`

(Your Office version number may differ)